# Demora en carga scritps en google sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

actualmente tengo un scripts que se ejecuta con normalidad, pero el tiempo de respuesta es muy alto y suele enviarme un error en el que excedo el limite de ejecución.  ¿existe una manera de reducir o mejorar la sentencia de mi código?

```js
function sumColoredCells(sumRange, colorRef) {

  var activeRg = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange();
  var activeSht = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  
  var activeformula = activeRg.getFormula();
  var countRangeAddress = activeformula.match(/\((.*)\,/).pop().trim();
  var backGrounds = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getBackgrounds();
  var sumValues = activeSht.getRange(countRangeAddress).getValues();
  var colorRefAddress = activeformula.match(/\,(.*)\)/).pop().trim();
  var BackGround = activeSht.getRange(colorRefAddress).getBackground();
  var totalValue = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < backGrounds.length; i++)
    for (var k = 0; k < backGrounds[i].length; k++)
      if (backGrounds[i][k] == BackGround)
        if ((typeof sumValues[i][k]) == 'number')
          totalValue = totalValue + (sumValues[i][k]);
  return totalValue;

}
```

El scripts me funciona y lo uso actualmente en mi hoja de trabajo pero tarda demasiado en calcular el valor. cada vez que carga se suman como 2 o 3 celdas y luego vuelve a cargar, termina y lo mismo asi hasta completar todas las celdas con formula.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando llega un punto que queda cargando y me da error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la formula que uso es:

=sumColoredCells(BS$305:BS$665,$AA7)

en conjunto con el scripts que tengo arriba.

Comment: Agrega más detalles, como datos de ejemplo, el resultado esperado, una breve descripción de cómo estás usando la función y el mensaje de error textual.

Comment: Te adelanto que seguramente tendrás que cambiar la forma en la estás usando tu script y adaptarlo a la nueva forma, por ejemplo, en lugar de llamar la función desde una fórmula podrías usar un menú personalizado, para lo cual tendrías que determinar como se determinará la fuente de los parámetros, etc.

Comment: ya actualice la pregunta. cualquier otra duda me comentas. gracias por el apoyo.

Comment: Gracias jose. Siempre que sea posible, código, datos , errores, logs, etc. deben agregarse como texto. En el caso de datos de la hojas de cálculo puede usarse markdow para agregarlos como tablas. Esto con la finalidad de que otros puedan reproducir el problema.

Comment: También considera que otros no tienen los mismos recursos que tú. En mi caso particular las capturas de pantalla me resulta ilegibles en el monitor que estoy  usando en estos momentos y no tengo tiempo de hacer zoom y paneo. De todas formas parece que lo que te adelantaba en uno de mis comentarios previos pareciera ser la mejor forma de proceder.

Comment: ya las cargue de nuevo Rubén disculpa estas si están legibles.  y markdow no conozco esta herramienta la chequeare para carga mi información. gracias igualmente por el apoyo y la paciencia.

Comment: Gracias jose. En cuanto al markdown, en la barra de herramientas del editor de Stack Overflow está el botón ? que incluye tips de formato, incluyendo tablas.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que se puede ver en la imágen que muestra la celda con el error, estás llamando la función en una fórmula, los parámetros abarcan muchas celdas y la hoja de cálculo es compleja.

Considerando lo anterior, lo mejor es que cambies el enfoque y en lugar de usar una función personaliza, modifiques tu script para lograr el mismo efecto llamado tu función de otra manera. Entre las opciones están usar un menú personalizado, usar uno o varios activadores instalables, por ejemplo, "on open", "on edit" o "on change".

Lo anterior debido a que las funciones personalizadas tiene un tiempo límite de ejecución de 30 segundos el cual no se puede extender, las métodos de Apps Script son relativamente lentos y cada vez que se cambie una celda includida en los parámetros de la fórmula esta se recalculará y si tienes dependencias la hoja de cálculo tomará más tiempo.

Algo que podrías explorar es usar el servicio avanzado de Google Sheets, que es bastante más eficiente, pero valora bien si tienes el tiempo para experimentar porque quizás dicho servicio no sea lo sufiente rápido para tu caso particular.

Comment: ya y como podria lograr este enfonque porque yo agregaria un menu al final lo que haria es el llamado de mi funcion pero como puedo adaptar el open on edit o el change a mi funcion para hacerla mas viable y no me consuma tanto el tiempo de respuesta. disculpa mis dudas.